# Unable to load managed table with maptype column (complex datatype) from external table in hive

Tags: hive, hdfs, hiveql, complex-data-types

I have external table with complex datatype,(map(string,array(struct))) and I'm able to select and query this external table without any issue.
However if I am trying to load this data to a managed table, it runs forever. Is there any best approach to load this data to managed table in hive?

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE DB.TBL( 
  id string ,
  list map<string,array<struct<ID:string,col:boolean,col2:string,col3:string,col4:string>>> 
) LOCATION <path>
```

Answer (score 1):

BTW, you can convert table to managed (though this may not work on cloudera distribution due warehouse dir restriction):

```
use DB;
alter table TBLSET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='FALSE');
```

If you need to load into another managed table, you can simply copy files into it's location.

--Create managed table (or use existing one)

```
use db;
create table tbl_managed(id string, 
                 list map<string,array<struct<ID:string,col:boolean,col2:string,col3:string,col4:string>>> ) ;

 --Check table location
use db;
desc formatted tbl_managed;
```

This will print location along with other info, use it to copy files.

Copy all files from external table location into managed table location, this will work most efficiently, much faster than insert..select:

```
hadoop fs -cp external/location/path/* managed/location/path
```

After copying files, table will be selectable. You may want to analyze table to compute statistics:

```
ANALYZE TABLE db_name.tablename COMPUTE STATISTICS [FOR COLUMNS]
```

Comment: This solution works if it is one time, But i need to load managed table daily with insert overwrite. Without list (map) column query runs fine. Any solution to handle this complex datatype would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Shine What is the problem with daily run, please explain what does not work. You can copy new files every day. And what do you mean complex type handling? I do not know how complex type is connected with slow load. It can be something else, need execution details: loading script, query plan, execution logs to understand what is working slow